# Publish Azure functions when not in root directory

Tags: node.js, function, azure, azure-functions-core-tools

I have node functions that i deploy to Azure functionapp using azure-functions-core-tools.

If I move my functions folders to a subdirectory ex `src` and run `func azure functionapp publish myapp` from `src`, only the functions code is packed and deployed without the rest of the project. When running from the root-directory and functions are in `src`, looks like the functions because in subdirectory are not detected and deployed.

Is there a way to indicate the path to the functions when deploying with azure-functions-core-tools from root?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible, take a look at [Azure Functions JavaScript Folder Structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#folder-structure).

It can be configured using the [scriptFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#using-scriptfile) property in file `function.json`.

```
{
  "scriptFile": "../lib/nodeFunction.js",
  "bindings": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This was helpful. You still need to have the functions folders with the `function.json` file in the root directory but using the scriptFile I was able to have all functions `index.js` in the same `src` directory.

Comment: Did you find any better solution?